# How to send an direct push notification with PushSharp within a Windows Service?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, windows-services, asp.net-web-api2, pushsharp

I have a virtual machine on azure with an Asp.net WebApi and a Windows Service with PushSharp.I want to send an push notification from the web api.Do I have to send a command to windows service or can i do something else?